# How can I use Heroku Scheluder Standard to automatize backups?

Tags: heroku, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, add-on

As you can say, I have an app running in Heroku, recently I installed Heroku Scheluder Standard add-on to automatize `heroku pgbackups:capture --expire --app my-app`, but it's been 3 days and it doesn't make the backup, so…

How can I make it do them?

Comment: You running a scheduled job at Heroku to run a `heroku pgbackups:capture` command that is usually run from outside Heroku, correct?

Comment: correct, that's usually runned from command line, but I want to automatize it, so I don't have to do it all days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the [`pgbackups`](https://addons.heroku.com/pgbackups) addon will work for you, depending on the frequency with which you want the backups to occur. `heroku addons:add pgbackups:auto-month` will configure the appropriate addon.